# Manifest.xml error i do not know at all

Tags: java, android

I do not know at all..
I use the various methods are not resolved

```
07-18 15:09:15.697: E/AndroidRuntime(22016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 15:09:15.697: E/AndroidRuntime(22016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kr.co.crooz.plugin.googleplustestplugin/kr.co.crooz.plugin.googleplustestplugin.AndroidGooglePlus}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
07-18 15:09:15.697: E/AndroidRuntime(22016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 15:09:15.697: E/AndroidRuntime(22016): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

AndroidGooglePlus.java 
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in code

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kr.co.crooz.plugin.googleplustestplugin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity 
            android:name="kr.co.crooz.plugin.googleplustestplugin.AndroidGooglePlus" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
           <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I need help. please.

meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"

Although the code is still an error occurs.

Comment: Please move meta-data out side activity tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `<meta-data>` tag outside `<activity>` tag and inside `<application>` tag.

Like so.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    >
    <activity 
       ......
     ......
    </activity>

   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Comment: @user3839298 If this answer solver your problem, accept the answer - it's the StackOverflow way.

Comment: @user3839298 accept and upvote this one if it resolved your issue